# List a View's Children SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to list a custom `View`'s children? For example, if I have a structure like `Group` am I able to list all child `View`s? Here is an example:

```
ParentView {
    Child1()
    Child2()
    Child3()
}
```

Is there a method that I can call on `ParentView` which will return an array containing `Child1`, `Child2`, and `Child3`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What would you do with this data?

Comment: @Fogmeister Specifically I want to populate the child views with data from the parent view, but it would be good to know how to do this for several purposes.

Comment: Thanks. Moreover, it seems odd to me that I would have to the same object to each child "view".

Comment: If you mean passing the data to the children? You wouldn't. You can either use `@State` to pass a binding `$varName` to the children or you can use an EnvironmentObject to do this. Please check out the WWDC videos. They go into this in a lot of detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwiftUI brings with it an entire paradigm shift of how UI works.

When you create a view like...

```
ParentView {
    Child1()
    Child2()
}
```

You are not actually creating views. Likewise there shouldn't be a reason to inspect the state of the views.

> With SwiftUI the view structure is a function of the data.

That is, when your data changes, your view hierarchy will update to reflect those changes.

This also means that data flow is one way. From your data... into the views. You do not get data from the views.

Because of this, you should not be inspecting the views like this. You should be inspecting the data that creates the views to find out about the data that way.

**UPDATE**

Equally, if you want to populate the child views with data from the parent view then you should be using `@State` object to hold this data and then update the data which will reload the view.

Something like this...

```
struct MyUpdatingView: View {
    @State private var items: [Int] = []

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { updateItems() }) {
                Text("New item")
            }

            List(items) { item in
                Text("Item: \(item)")
            }
        }
    }

    func updateItems() {
        items.append(items.count)
    }
}
```

This will create a view that updates its `@State` data which then in turn reloads the view with the new data.

Comment: Thanks for the side note, that is very helpful. That wasn't exactly what I was trying to ask. The crux of my problem is I would like to make a component where I don't know what type the child view will be so the user can pass the parent view anything (similar to how `VStack` or `Group` works). Does that make sense? Thank you for your time on this issue :)

Comment: @zoecarver not sure if you're still looking for an answer to this, but I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56961821/how-to-access-to-the-children-views-in-swiftui/56998617#56998617). Let me know if that helps.