# How to access to the children views in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm working on the SwiftUI, and feeling it's very similar with React. Just now I'm customizing a Button of SwiftUI and have a problem which can't access to the children views of Button dynamically
Following codes is what I'm going to do:

```
struct FullButton : View {
  var action: () -> Void
  var body: some View {
    Button(action: action) {
      // render children views here even what is that
      children
    }
  }
}
```

and usage:

```
VStack {
  FullButton(action: {
    print('touched')
  }) {
    Text("Button")
  }
}
```

Please, do I have a wrong idea?

## Update

Depends on @graycampbell 's answer I tried as following

```
struct FullButton<Label> where Label : View {
    var action: () -> Void
    var label: () -> Label

    init(action: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder label: @escaping () -> Label) {
        self.action = action
        self.label = label
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action, label: label)
    }
}
```

So the `FullButton` looks well as itself. But I have another compile error in usage at this time.

```
VStack {
    FullButton(action: { print("touched") }) {
        Text("Fullbutton")
    }
}
```

The error is `Referencing initializer 'init(alignment:spacing:content:)' on 'VStack' requires that 'FullButton<Text>' conform to 'View'`.
It means `FullButton` hasn't return the `body` now?
I'm not sure why it is because the `FullButton` still extends `View` class.
Please let me know what's the correct `body` definition of that type of class.

Comment: You don’t “access the children”, but rather you declare them them to render according to some `@State` variables and your button’s handler would just update those state variables. You might want to edit your question with some practical example of what sort of UI change you want the tapping of the button to trigger.

Comment: Have you found out how to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what you're looking for, if I'm understanding your question correctly:

```swift
struct FullButton<Label>: View where Label: View {
    var action: () -> Void
    var label: () -> Label

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: self.action, label: self.label)
    }
}
```

This would allow you to pass whatever content you want to be displayed on your button, meaning that the code you have here would now work:

```swift
FullButton(action: {
    print("touched")
}) {
    Text("Button")
}
```

## Update

After looking over your question several times, I've realized that your confusion is stemming from a misunderstanding of what is happening when you create a normal `Button`.

In the code below, I'm creating a `Button`. The button takes two arguments - `action` and `label`.

```swift
Button(action: {}, label: {
    Text("Button")
})
```

If we look at the documentation for `Button`, we see that it is declared like this:

```swift
struct Button<Label> where Label : View
```

If we then look at the initializers, we see this:

```swift
init(action: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label)
```

Both `action` and `label` expect closures. `action` expects a closure with a return type of `Void`, and `label` expects a `@ViewBuilder` closure with a return type of `Label`. As defined in the declaration for `Button`, `Label` is a generic representing a `View`, so really, `label` is expecting a closure that returns a `View`.

This is not unique to `Button`. Take `HStack`, for example:

```swift
struct HStack<Content> where Content : View

init(alignment: VerticalAlignment = .center, spacing: Length? = nil, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)
```

`Content` serves the same purpose here that `Label` does in `Button`.

Something else to note - when we create a button like this...

```swift
Button(action: {}) {
    Text("Button")
}
```

...we're actually doing the same thing as this:

```swift
Button(action: {}, label: {
    Text("Button")
})
```

In Swift, when the last argument in a method call is a closure, we can omit the argument label and append the closure to the outside of the closing parenthesis.

**In SwiftUI, you cannot implicitly pass content to any `View`. The `View` must explicitly accept a `@ViewBuilder` closure in its initializer.**

And so, you cannot pass a `@ViewBuilder` closure to `FullButton` unless `FullButton` accepts a `@ViewBuilder` closure as an argument in its initializer, as shown at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Would it be possible to "spread" all existing `Button` initializer parameters as well as modifiers straight through from the `FullButton` wrapper instead of having to duplicate them all one by one and pass them down as shown here?

Comment: Since SwiftUI uses `struct` and not `class` for views, you can’t subclass `Button`. `Button` is also not a `protocol`, and even if it was, I imagine you’d still have to add property declarations. You could pass a `Button` through the initializer of `FullButton`, but I feel like that’s starting to beg the question why you’re wrapping `Button` with `FullButton` to begin with, and if there is a better way to achieve whatever goal it is that you have. I tried to focus mainly on answering the poster’s original question rather than object to what they’re doing since I don’t know their reasoning.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate your input. In React, there's a fairly common pattern of taking a component and applying maybe one or two new attributes to it (e.g. a behavior or a visual style) but passing everything else straight through https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#use-hocs-for-cross-cutting-concerns

Comment: But in SwiftUI it seems like it may be preferable to use alternatives like custom modifiers or closures imported and applied without necessarily wrapping the View in a new View.

Comment: @graycampbell, thanks for your answer but I still haven't fixed my problem, would you check my updates of question?

Comment: @rener172846 Look at the line `struct FullButton<Label> where Label : View`. It should be `struct FullButton<Label>: View where Label : View`. The error you're getting is telling you that `FullButton` does not conform to `View`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [ViewInspector](https://github.com/nalexn/ViewInspector) library that uses Swift's reflection for extracting SwiftUI views from any hierarchy.

```
let view = FullButton()
let button = try view.inspect().button()
let children = button.anyView().view(OtherView.Type)
// By the way, you can even tap the button programmatically:
try button.tap()
```

Comment: Is this safe for production?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov it depends on what you consider dangerous here. Apple review rejection? No risk here, the library isn't using private API. Overall app's stability? Maybe, depends on how you use it. If you're using it the way it's built for, that is for unit testing, - then you're safe.